# What is actually happening in lwz?

Tags: assembly, powerpc, instructions

I am looking at the following instruction and I can't seem to understand it. I've tried to read a couple of online PowerPC instruction references but they are not very understandable to me.

```
lwz       r4, dword_91C0DB28@l(r28)
```

Here how the dword shows in IDA

```
dword_91C0DB28: .long 0
```

What exactly is going on when lwz is called and why is it useful?

Comment: `lwz` loads a word at the memory address given and zeros the upper 32 bits. What's unclear about it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen What is the purpose of `r28` in this instance if the address we want to load is `dword_91C0DB28`?

Comment: _"the address we want to load is dword_91C0DB28"_. It's not. `dword_91C0DB28` is just the displacement, while the base address is given in `r28`. The effective address is base_address + sign_extend(displacement). `r28` might in this case contain the address of the beginning of the section where `dword_91C0DB28` is located.

Comment: @Michael This is what it shows is loaded into r28 `lis       r28, ((dword_91C0DB28+0x10000)@h)`. I'm still not sure what it's calculating or why it'd need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the answer above is not correct.

***IDA instruction:***

```
lwz       r4, dword_91C0DB28@l(r28)
```

Instruction above access to memory `dword_91C0DB28` itself.
This memory address is calculated by IDA's analyse heuristics.

***Original instruction:***

```
lwz        r4, -12345(r28)
```

In this moment the real instruction would be like above.
The address`0x91C0DB28` you've seen at IDA would be made by `$r28` - 12345 during runtime.
*(Offset -12345 is just an example).*

***FYI:*** *You can see original instruction by using dumb disassemblers such as `objdump`.*

Answer (score 3):

`lwz` loads a word to the target register from the memory address defined and zeros the upper 32 bits. In this case the target is `r4` and memory address is `dword_91X0DB28 + r28`.

Comment: I understand it now, the `@l` and `@h` after which loads the lower and higher bits of our dword.

Comment: @Aidan: No, `@l` takes the low 16 bits of the *address*, not of the pointed-to dword (actually `.long`, a single PowerPC word).  Presumably `r28` was first initialized with `lis r28, foo@h` to get the high 16 bits into the top of the register.